# R function defined but not showing as object

Tags: r

I have defined a function but it is not holding as an object. Here's the code I have used:

```
ba<-function(dbh_cm) {
pi*(dbh_cm) ^ 2
}
```

It will run and produce results but it is just not showing as an object, and I cannot recall it as an object.

Comment: Run the line `ba<-function(dbh_cm) { pi*(dbh_cm) ^ 2 }` in the console. You can then use function `ba(10)`.

Comment: That's worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to source it first. Right top.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried that but I have the same issue. Now I cannot even get a result from the function. I'm very new to R (started this week) so I'm sure I'm doing something daft, but it seems like I am getting completely inconsistent results with functions.